# Cannot open file libmfx_vs2015.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intel-media-sdk

I downloded the sample session from the intel media sdk and tried to build it .
But unfortunatly it always says :"cannot open file 'libmfx_vs2015.lib'" . 
I have looked on many solutions saying i should change the path of the linker in the project propertires but it didn't change anything about the build.
Can anyone point me in the right direction or atleast point me to a decent tutorial on how to use the media sdk api ?

Cahnging the path for the additional lib

LNK1104 cannot open file'libmfx_vs2015.lib'

Comment: This means either of 3 things. 1. The fie named incorrectly (does not match what you typed) or it is in the wrong folder. 2. The file is corrupt. or 3. You are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Does the file exist anywhere on your system if you search for it?

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you it solved the issue-  i forgot to set the solution platform to 64. Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LNK1104 cannot open file 'libmfx_vs2015.lib' (or any other library) usually means one of the following three things:

1. The file was not found in the library search paths. It could be named differently or the path is not in your `Linker->General->Additional Library Directories` setting for the current configuration or the system wide directories property page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?view=vs-2019
2. The library is corrupt in some way.
3. You could also be mixing 32 and 64 bit binaries. Your application bitlevel must match the library so if the library is 64 bit make sure you are using the x64 configuration for your application in Visual Studio.